# T$\mathbb{S}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

My strategy is find a diffeomorphism $\psi: T\mathbb{S}^{n} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{S}^{n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ from other diffeomorphisms. First let $(\mathbb{R},Id_{\mathbb{R}})$ the 1-dimensional euclidean space with canonical chart, which is a global chart. Then $T\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, thus

$T\mathbb{S}^{n} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{(Id)^{-1}} T\mathbb{S}^{n}\times T\mathbb{R}$,

Now, the product of tangent bundles are diffeomorphic to tangent bundle of T($\mathbb{S}^{n}\times \mathbb{R})$, thus

$T\mathbb{S}^{n} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{(Id)^{-1}} T\mathbb{S}^{n}\times T\mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{\phi} T(\mathbb{S^{n}\times \mathbb{R})}$.

where $\phi:T(\mathbb{S}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}) \to T\mathbb{S}^{n}\times T\ \mathbb{R}$ is a diffeomorphism mentioned above. My question is there exists a global chart for $\mathbb{S}^{n}\times \mathbb{R}$? If it is true this problem is over. Right?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to conclude this way, as $TS^n$ is not a trivial bundle. Moreover, I believe there are non diffeomorphic spaces with diffeomorphic tangent bundle (even if I can't find an example now).

Instead, you can notice that the vector bundle $V = \{ (x,v) : x \in S^n, v \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \}$ is trivial, in particular diffeomorphic to $S^n \times \mathbb R^{n+1}$.

But if $T = \{ (x,v) : x \in S^n, v \in \mathbb R^{n+1}, \langle x, v \rangle = 0 \}$ and  $N = \{ (x,v) : x \in S^n \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}, v  = \lambda x \}$, we have an isomorphism $T \oplus N \cong V$. Do you see how this solve your problem ?

Comment: Hey @N.H. i do not have the vector bundle theory at hand. My only tools are the chapters 1,2,3 of introduction to smooth manifolds of J.Lee. This question apparead in an examination of my class of smooth manifolds.

Comment: In non-bundle langage : $V$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n \times \mathbb R^n$, $T$ to $TS^n$ and $N$ to $S^n \times \mathbb R$.

Comment: $V$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, right?.

Comment: I think you should replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ in a few places.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval : sure, thanks.

Comment: @C.Junior : this is right !

Answer (score 3):

I think that you were on the right track from the beginning.

Consider the smooth embedding $~\psi:\mathbb{S}^n\times\mathbb{R}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ given by
$$\psi((x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}),t)=(\alpha(t)x_1,\dots,\alpha(t)x_{n+1})$$
where $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is any diffeomorphism. Then we obtain an induced diffeomorphism
$$T\psi:(\mathbb{S}^{n}\times\mathbb{R})\xrightarrow{\cong}(\mathbb{S}^n\times\mathbb{R})\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$

Then we have a composition of diffeomorphisms:
$$T\mathbb{S}^{n} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{\text{id}^{-1}} T\mathbb{S}^{n}\times T\mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{\phi} T(\mathbb{S^{n}\times \mathbb{R})}\xrightarrow{T\psi} \mathbb{S}^n\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$

We conclude by noting that $T\mathbb{S}^n\times\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}$ maps to $\mathbb{S}^n\times\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ under the composition above.